# how to locate akka actors non actor contexes?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In my app I have a few places where I use actors (for example sending messages to external systems etc).

Now I need to locate one of those actors from a different part of the system which is not related to actors (in example in `JMX` I want to utilize some of the system which expects to be able to receive an `actor` as a method `parameter`) - (Dependency injection i'm injecting that actor in that method which requires it).  If in jmx I was inside actor context I could locate it with perhaps with `actorSelection` however the jmx is not in actor context so i cannot locate it, what would be the best practice for locating that actor from my `jmx` context?